# Need to detect the column while using sqlldr

Tags: oracle, file, oracle12c, sql-loader

OS: WIN
Database target: Oracle 12c 
Source is File.
Using : sqlldr

I have a text data in this format. I have pasted the sample data in the description (please copy it to notepad++) i have huge data in this way which i would like to load it into the database table using sqlldr.

let me give you a brief of data TRN is where the transaction starts and TRNEND is where it ends.

The problem is- TRN1111111119134 record line where we have one column missing but that is present in transaction TRN1111111117134 column which is 114115, but my requirement here is to insert null into that column corresponding down to 114115 in first transaction when dealing with the second transaction but everything here is separated by white space(can we convert the white space delimiter to fixed one or other delimited one dynamically ?).
Any advice would really be helpful. Thanks a lot.

```
TRN1111111117134  211712221635361341111576114115    114115    CLOSE CT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    J                        J                    J                                                                                                                        JOS
TRNEND11111111181111111111
TRN1111111119134  21171222163536                              TOTAL CTT                                                                                                           VOUCH                                                                                                                   J11111111111115221111    J                    J                                                                                                                        JOS
TRNEND11111111111111111111
```

I am trying to use below sqlldr control file command, do i missing something here ?

```
infile 'D:\Source_files\LOG_07117_2017.DAT'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

truncate into table RAW_FILE
 fields terminated by WHITESPACE optionally enclosed by '#'
 TRAILING NULLCOLS
 (  col1 , 
    col2 "nvl(:col2,'')",
    col3 "nvl(:col3,'')", 
    col4 "nvl(:col4,'')",
    col5 "nvl(:col5,'')",
    col6  "nvl(:col6,'')",
    col7 "nvl(:col7,'')",
    col8 "nvl(:col8,'')",
    col9 "nvl(:col9,'')",
    col10 "nvl(:col10,'')",
    col11 "nvl(:col11,'')",
    col12 "nvl(:col12,'')",
    col13 "nvl(:col13,'')",
    col14 "nvl(:col14,'')",
    col15 "nvl(:col15,'')",
    col16 "nvl(:col16,'')",
    col17 "nvl(:col17,'')",
    col18 "nvl(:col18,'')",
    col19 "nvl(:col19,'')",
    col20 "nvl(:col20,'')",
    col21 "nvl(:col21,'')",
    col22 "nvl(:col22,'')",
    col23 "nvl(:col23,'')",
    col24 "nvl(:col24,'')",
    col25 "nvl(:col25,'')",
    col26 "nvl(:col26,'')",
    col27 "nvl(:col27,'')",
    col28 "nvl(:col28,'')",
    col29 "nvl(:col29,'')",
    col30 "nvl(:col30,'')")
```

The table definition for this case

```
CREATE TABLE "RAW_FILE" (
     "COL1"     VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
     "COL2"     VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
     "COL3"     VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
     "COL4"     VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
     "COL5"     VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
     "COL6"     VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
     "COL7"     VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
     "COL8"     VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
     "COL9"     VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
     "COL10"    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
     "COL11"    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
     "COL12"    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
     "COL13"    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
     "COL14"    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
     "COL15"    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
     "COL16"    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
     "COL17"    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
     "COL18"    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
     "COL19"    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
     "COL20"    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
     "COL21"    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
     "COL22"    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
     "COL23"    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
     "COL24"    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
     "COL25"    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
     "COL26"    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
     "COL27"    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
     "COL28"    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
     "COL29"    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
     "COL30"    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE))
```

Comment: Please include a table definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input appears to be a fixed format file; try to explain why "TOTAL" is the 4th field and not the 3rd, and it will probably become apparent why.

Replace the `fields terminated by WHITESPACE optionally enclosed by '#'` with specific positions on each field, such as `col3 POSITION (53:62)` .

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment, i used to view the data in file as whitespace separated but not it makes sense look at it as fixed width, i never handled this kind of requirement prior, but all my past work need a modifications now, Thanks a lot.